# Arctoolbox and python

Tags: arcpy, arctoolbox

I am trying to use arctoolbox and python so that the user can enter in parameters. In my script I have the following lines

```
_StationInterval = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

I just want the user to be able to enter in a value for the station interval. However I get the error:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name '_StationInterval' is not defined
Failed to execute (Final3Test).
```

Before I used arctoolbox, I had the station interval set to a value in the script, i.e. 
_StationInterval = 10000

Am I missing something in my script??

Comment: Post the rest of your script so we can see what else is going on...

Comment: does the error occurring at the line you posted?

Comment: Uhm,...I think so. I mean, the arc toolbox doesn't tell me a line of where the error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably fine but it sounds like you have not defined a Parameter for it on the Properties of your Python script tool.

The process for doing that is described **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_script_tool_parameters/00150000002s000000/)**.

Comment: I have already defined and set the parameters within the properties box of arctoolbox. I'm still getting the same error. Is there some snippet of code I need to include in actual python script (other than what I've posted above) to define the parameters as well?

Comment: If you have defined a function within your Python script and the variable is set outside of it then you may have a scoping issue.  If that is the issue just pass it in as a parameter to the function.